# Change the order in which items appear in a latex beamer table

Tags: tables, beamer, pause

I have read that using `visibile<#->` option, where # is an integer number from 1, is possible to change the order in which some elements appear into the slides. However this doesn't seem to work in the example below, can you help me?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    In this case it is appropriate to choose $f(x) = x$ and $G(x) = \ln x$.
    
    \pause    
    
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \visible<2->{$F(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$}    & \visible<1->{$f(x) = x$} \\ 
        \visible<1->{$G(x) = \ln x$}            & \visible<3->{$g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$}
    \end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In other words, it must appear in the order

1. f(x) and G(x)
2. F(x), in addition to the one in the previous point
3. g(x), in addition to the one in the previous point.

Comment: Works fine for me if I add all the stuff necessary to compile the code fragment. Can you please make a small, but compilable test document so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: This is the result I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aqA4.gif

Comment: Ok I figured out the problem is when I use /pause option before the tabular. Now it works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `\pause` before your table, you want to start your uncovering on the second overlay instead of the first overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

In this case it is appropriate to choose $f(x) = x$ and $G(x) = \ln x$.

\pause    

\begin{tabular}{cc}
        \visible<3->{$F(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$}        & \visible<2->{$f(x) = x$} \\ 
        \visible<2->{$G(x) = \ln x$}                & \visible<4->{$g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$}
    \end{tabular}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]